# Flask forms, custom validation errors/functions

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a login() function in my form, I would like to return errors on specific fields in it, my questions is, how I could do something like that, this is my current function:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = models.User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()

        if user is None:
            raise ValidationError('Such user not found')

    def login(self, user):
        if check_password_hash(user.password, self.password.data):

            flash('Logged in successfully!', category='success')

            login_user(user, remember=self.remember.data)

            return True

        else:
            raise LoginException('Wrong Password')
```

Should I just maybe flash the errors or should I remake it into a seperate validate password function? If there is a way I could for example return the LoginException so it gets displayed under my password field, I would be happy to know.

Comment: You haven't shown any `WTForm`. You would access them with the `.errors` attribute but there's nowhere near enough info in your question to help you fix this

Comment: Ok, added the whole form, is there anything more I should provide? Well the .errors is empty as the login function is not field specific, should I split the function into a validate_password() function?

Comment: Why do you validate the password in the form and not in the user model?

Comment: If I would validate it in the model, then I couln't return any errors that would appear under the field

Comment: Why do you want to tell the user whether the email exists or the password is incorrect. In terms of security, this is not really reasonable. Use flash messages as an alternative to the error message under the form field.

Comment: It makes no sense to have `login` as a method on your form. It should be a method on your `User` class. You only want the form to validate that the submitted values are sensible, you _don't_ want to have the form perform the login. How does `user.password` even exist? You're putting their password into a session?

Comment: user.password is a hash of the password, check_password_hash compares an input password that it hashes and a hashed password from the database.

Comment: Well I guess I will move it to the model, but it would keep the user model tidier if I place that in the view specific form wouldn't it?

Comment: But yeah you are right about the specificness of the flashed errors, I guess I am just going to raise and log these errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution for you. Is that what you want?

```
def valid_credentials(form, field):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    return user and user.verify_password(form.password.data)


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if not valid_credentials(self, field):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid user credentials.')

    def validate_password(self, field):
        if not valid_credentials(self, field):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid user credentials.')

class User(db.Model):
    email = db.Column(db.String,
        nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String,
        nullable=False, unique=False, index=False)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
```

You can also move `valid_credentials (form, field)` into the form and/or only pass one validation function to the `validators` list.

Make sure that you do not tell the user which form field contains the error and that the user may be able to guess the access data more easily.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will do something like this then, thank you.